# how to send no shipping from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

How not to send shipping addresses using WordPress? How to hide shipping address in paypal?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNP3h.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack OVerflow. Where is yoru code? We help people with coding problems, not with a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what integration / WordPress Plugin you are using. Perhaps it includes an option to not collect a shipping address as part of the checkout.

If t does not, and if it uses PayPal's v2/checkout/orders API, the [orders create request body](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body) must include an `application_context` object with `shipping_preference` set to `NO_SHIPPING`.

Comment: No plugins are used for this, only the PayPal payment plugin is used.

Comment: Now, I am trying to hide the Address filed while selecting Local Pickup

Comment: Any way of sending noshipping using function.php?

Comment: I don't know what that is. Whatever creates the order with PayPal (REST API create order or JavaScript SDK `createOrder`), is the section of the code that needs to include the additional parameter.

Comment: I am getting CITY_REQUIRED The specified country requires a city (address.admin_area_2)

Comment: That means you are sending a partial shipping address. If your intention is to use NO_SHIPPING, don't send any address information.